# Junit testing missing tests

Tags: java, testing, junit, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm writing tests for Junit to test a delete function that I wrote:

```
/**
     * Deletes the item at the given index. If there are any elements located at a higher
     * index, shift them all down by one.
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index < 0 or index >= this.size()
     */
```

```
@Override
    public T delete(int index)  {
        if (index < 0 || index > this.size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } else if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyContainerException();
        } else {
            Node<T> current = front;
            if (index == 0) {
                front = current.next;
                current.prev = null;
                size--;
                return current.data;
            } else if (index == size - 1) {
                return remove();
            } else {
                current = traverse(current, index);
                Node<T> temp = current;
                current.prev.next = current.next;
                current.next.prev = current.prev;
                size--;
                return temp.data;
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is for a double linked list that has both a back and front node.

THE PROBLEM: Our college will run buggy code against the tests we write to determine whether we've written enough tests to catch bad code and exceptions.

I know 2 of the tests that they will run, but don't know what the error means.

- FAIL: MissingBackFieldRepairLogic

  ```
  Unable to find bug with DoubleLinkedList with missing back field repair logic
  ```
- FAIL: MissingNextNodeRepairLogic

  ```
  Unable to find bug with DoubleLinkedList with missing next node repair logic
  ```

These^ are 2 tests that I have not accounted for as I'm unable to understand what theses errors mean. Does anyone have any idea about what these errors might be?

And what kind of tests should I write to catch these errors?

Thanks
-A desperate student

Comment: We don't need to see an implementation of the method under test itself.  In fact, that's a distraction when it comes to talking about designing tests.  What you need to consider is *the specifications* that the method is required to satisfy, including the specifications for how errors and exceptional cases are to be handled.  THAT's largely what should drive which tests you write.

Comment: My crystal ball is a bit cloudy with regard to the specific failure messages you presented, but my guess would be that they are directed at cases where the method under test doesn't work for the first and/or last element of the list.  Alternatively, they almost sound like they are expecting some kind of recovery of cases where the list structure has been corrupted.

Comment: Thank you for the reply guys @JohnBollinger could you please give me an example, and explain what you mean by that so that I can write a test based on that'

Comment: The specifications for the method are added in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadoc is not necessarily the same thing as specifications, but supposing that Javadocs are all that you are given or that the docs presented adequately capture the full specifications, I would test these cases:

**Error cases**

In each of these cases, verify that the correct exception is thrown.

- The argument is negative
- The argument is equal to the current size of the list
- Including when the list is initially empty

**Normal cases**

In each of these cases verify that the correct object is returned, and that the elements remaining in the list are correct, and in the correct order.

- Deleting from a single-element list
- Deleting the first element from a two-element list
- Deleting the first element from a longer list
- Deleting the last element from a two-element list
- Deleting the last element from a longer list
- Deleting an interior element of a list

It is not clear what the two cases you specifically asked about mean, but I would guess that they have to do with flaws in maintaining the internal consistency of the list during deletions.  How you might check for such flaws depends on the structure of the list, the methods it provides, and what internal details, if any, it exposes.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer